# Axios NodeJs - obteniendo access token

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, axios

Hola amigos estoy tratando de recibir mi token de un api , pero cuando 
trato de tomarlo como parte del objeto **reqtoken** me lo da undefined, ya comprobé y si recibo todos los datos.

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const axios= require('axios');

router.get('/accesstoken', (req, res) => {

    let tok ="";

    const reqtoken = axios.request({
       
        method: "post",
        baseURL: "https://api.token",
        auth: {
          username: process.env.OAUTHK,
          password: process.env.SCT
        },
        data: {
          "grant_type": "client_credentials",
          "scope": "public"    
        }
      }).then(function(res) {
        //console.log(res.data.access_token);  
       
        let data = res.data;
        //console.log(datax.access_token);

        return data;
    
    }).catch((er)=>{
        console.log(er);
         
      });

      console.log(reqtoken.data);
     // res.render('links/bbvat',{reqbbva: reqbbva});


});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Actualización:**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const axios = require('axios');

router.get('/accesstoken', (req, res) => {

  function getTokenFromServer() {
  return axios.request({
      method: "post",
      baseURL: "https://api.token",
      auth: {
        username: process.env.OAUTHK,
        password: process.env.SCT
      },
      data: {
        "grant_type": "client_credentials",
        "scope": "public"
      }
    }).then(function (res) {
      //console.log(res.data.access_token);             
      return res.data;
      //console.log(datax.access_token);

    }).catch((er) => {
      console.log(er);
    });
    console.log(tok);
    //console.log(reqtoken);
    // res.render('links/bbvat',{reqbbva: reqbbva});
  }

  getTokenFromServer().then(data => {
    console.log(data);
  });

});
```

Comment: me devuelve un > Promise { <pending> }, si intento un reqtoken.data me da undefined

Comment: @E.Rawrdríguez.Ophanim respuesta actualizada, revisa nuevamente por favor :D

Comment: me deja con el explorador en espera ... terminal no me tira nada, si estoy recibiendo los datos pero no tok :s

Comment: ¿Utilizas postman u alguna otra herramienta para verificar que la url y el paso de datos son los adecuados?

Comment: si si, utilizo postman, y efectivamente, los datos si llegan, si uso console.log(res.data) puedo ver todo lo que llega, pero no puedo darselo a una variable, para poder renderizarlo con handlebars, espero haber sido claro

Comment: ¿y si pones `var tok;` en lugar de `var tok = "";` ?

Comment: @E.Rawrdríguez.Ophanim actualizada nuevamente, veamos qué sale :D